# How to avoid IllegalStateException attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

My problem is next. On some devices I get the Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException. I open the SQLDatabase once in MyActivity OnCreate method (using getWritableDatabase()) and close it in Destroy method.
On emulators and my devices I could not get the error but get the error from users.
What did I miss. Could you help me to find? My brains are overloaded.

I posted the necessary code below.

Here is the `error`:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.example.project/databases/database.db
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference + 55(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory + 1296(SQLiteDatabase.java:1296)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query + 1172(SQLiteDatabase.java:1172)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query + 1340(SQLiteDatabase.java:1340)
at com.example.project.database.DBAdapter.getMyCursor + 607(DBAdapter.java:607)
at com.example.project.fragments.MyDetailFragment.onMethodCallback + 36(MyDetailFragment.java:236)
at com.example.project.adapter.MyRVAdapter$1$1.run + 124(MyRVAdapter.java:124)
```

Here is some code of `DBAdapter.class`

```
public Cursor getMyCursor(String whom) {

        String selection = DBHelper.MY.COL_WHOM + " = ?";
        String[] args = new String[]{whom};
        String orderBy = DBHelper.MY.COL_SEQ + " ASC";
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.MY.TABLE, null, selection, args, null, null, orderBy); //:607
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        return cursor;
    }
```

Here is some code of `MyDetailFragment`:

```
    private int position;
    private View view;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private DBAdapter mDBAdapter;
    private MyRVAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

        if (getActivity() instanceof MyActivity) {
            mDBAdapter = ((MyActivity) getActivity()).getDBAdapter();

        }

        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerDetail);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        .
        .//additional code
        .
        getList();

        return view;
    }

    private void getList() {
        if (mRecyclerView != null && mDBAdapter != null) {
            Cursor cursor = mDBAdapter.getMyCursor(getWhom(position));
            adapter = new MyRVAdapter(getContext(), cursor, this, mDBAdapter);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMethodCallback() {
        adapter.changeCursor(mDBAdapter.geMyCursor(getWhomBag(position))); //:236
    }
```

Comment: You can create singleton sqlitehekper class and don't close dB .

Comment: The issue might be a timing issue where the onDestroy() and and onCreate() code executes incorrectly. Ashok has a good idea to use a singleton, which you can then access with Async calls (for example). An alternative (havent tried these though) could be to create a fragment with setRetainInstance(true) OR to use a ModelView instead. These objects might not get recreated with every orientation change or minimise/maximise of your app - so there is less chance of an illegalStateException.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try.

Comment: It did'nt help me.